# Does it make sense to put custom class definition under /app in rails 3.2.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We would like to define a class for user privilege in our rails 3.2.8 app. This privilege class is called whenever the app is accessing the database to determine if a user has the access right. If we create a new subdir such as sys_class under `/app` for the user privilege class, does it make sense? Or it is better to create sys_class under `/lib` and include `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/sys_class)` in application.rb.

Comment: I'd put it in lib, I won't clutter app dir for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Fernando's answer - which users are allowed to do what in your application is part of the business logic, which means that it's really part of your model. So the class should go somewhere under `app/models`. You might put it in a subdirectory of that, if you want to separate it from your other model objects for some reason.

Model objects in your application don't have to map directly to database tables.

Answer (score 1):

In the CanCan this class is named Ability and is created in app/models

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/#1-define-abilities